# Deriving Uniplate with Derive

Tags: haskell, uniplate

My program is using [Uniplate.Data](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Data.html) extensively, and want to improve its performance.

Currently I'm deriving `Data` instances automatically using the `DeriveDataTypeable` GHC extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data

data Expr = Val Int
          | Neg Expr
          | Add Expr Expr
  deriving (Data,Typeable)
```

The [Uniplate.Data package description](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Data.html) recommend using [Uniplate.Direct](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Direct.html) because of superior performance.
The latter requires writing explicit `Uniplate` instances for data types, and recommend the [Derive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive-2.5.22) tool for that.

When trying to derive instances automatically using `Derive`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Data.DeriveTH
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Direct

data Expr = Val Int
          | Neg Expr
          | Add Expr Expr

$( derive makeUniplateDirect ''Expr )
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
  Derivation of UniplateDirect does not yet support Template Haskell, requires info for Expr
Code: derive makeUniplateDirect ''Expr
```

Is there any other way of deriving `Uniplate.Direct` instances automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, `UniplateDirect` doesn't support TH mode of `derive`, so you have to use the standalone executable version as a preprocessor to generate the `Uniplate` instance.

You can do this by adding `{-! !-}` directives, and setting `derive` as a preprocessor to be run by GHC:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmFderive -optF-F #-}
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Direct

data Expr = Val Int
          | Neg Expr
          | Add Expr Expr

{-!
deriving instance UniplateDirect Expr
!-}
```

Loading this into GHCi for a quick test confirms you have your instance:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( SO31725183.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :i Expr
data Expr = Val Int | Neg Expr | Add Expr Expr
        -- Defined at D:\cygwin\tmp\ghc13224_0\ghc13224_3.hspp:6:1
instance Uniplate Expr
  -- Defined at D:\cygwin\tmp\ghc13224_0\ghc13224_3.hspp:16:10
```